# Are there moves that would never be taught or talked about in an MMA gym?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, karate, mixed-martial-arts

because they're just too dangerous to the public or for public consumption? I assume they'd be slight modifications of the more dangerous moves that would be the ones actually taught.

Answer (score 5):

There is a list of illegal moves in MMA. People do not teach them because they are illegal. For example, [the UFC rules list](https://www.ufc.com/unified-rules-mixed-martial-arts):

- Butting with the head
- Eye gouging of any kind
- Biting or spitting at an opponent
- Fish hooking (act of inserting a finger or fingers or one or both hands into the mouth or nostrils or a person, pulling away from the centerline of the body)
- Hair pulling
- Spiking an opponent to the canvas on his head or neck
- Strikes to the spine or the back of the head.
- Throat strikes of any kind, and/or grabbing the trachea
- Fingers outstretched toward an opponent’s face/eyes
- Downward pointing elbow strike (’12 to ‘6 strike)
- Groin attacks of any kind
- Kneeing and/or kicking the head of a grounded opponent
- Stomping a grounded opponent
- Holding opponent’s gloves or shorts
- Holding or grabbing the fence or ropes with fingers or toes
- Small joint manipulation

Many of these do not have modifications to make them less dangerous; there are no slight modifications of small joint manipulation, stomping grounded opponents, groin attacks, or strikes to the back of the head.

Comment: whilst these wouldn't/shouldn't be taught in an MMA gym (set up for competition and not self defence at least) - they may be talked about in the sense of "don't do these they are illegal".

Comment: Also, dim mak, the touch of death.